# How to add loader to ajax

Tags: ajax, magento2.4.1, loader

How to apply loader script to my code,

Loader : https://meetanshi.com/blog/magento-2-show-loader-till-ajax-call-not-completed/

My code:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/authentication-popup',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
    'underscore',
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/decorate',
    'mage/collapsible',
    'mage/cookies'
], function ($, authenticationPopup, customerData, alert, confirm, _) {
    'use strict';
    return function (widget) {

        $.widget('mage.sidebar', widget, {

            _updateItemQty: function (elem) {
                var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');

                var btnplus = elem.data('btn-plus');
                var btnminus = elem.data('btn-minus');

                this._ajax(this.options.url.update, {
                    'item_id': itemId,
                    'item_qty': $('#cart-item-' + itemId + '-qty').val(),
                    'item_btn_plus': btnplus,
                    'item_btn_minus': btnminus
                }, elem, this._updateItemQtyAfter);
                this._customerData();
            },

            /**
             * Update content after update qty
             *
             * @param {HTMLElement} elem
             */
            _updateItemQtyAfter: function (elem) {
                var productData = this._getProductById(Number(elem.data('cart-item')));

                if (!_.isUndefined(productData)) {
                    $(document).trigger('ajax:updateCartItemQty');

                    if (window.location.href === this.shoppingCartUrl) {
                        window.location.reload(false);
                    }
                }
                this._hideItemButton(elem);
            },

            _customerData : function ()  {
                var sections = ['cart'];
                customerData.invalidate(sections);
                customerData.reload(sections, true);
            }

        });
       
        return $.mage.sidebar;
        
    }
    
});
```

How to apply the loader?

Answer (score 1):

You can show loader in multiple ways in Magento 2. Like:

> **First Way**:

**For Show Loader:** `$("body").trigger('processStart');`

**For Hide Loader:** `$("body").trigger('processStop');`

> **Second Way**: With the use of loader widget:

```
require(['jquery', 'loader'], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $("body").loader("show");
    $("body").loader("hide");
});
```

Check-in details here:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_loader.html

Answer (score 1):

Try processStart and processStop:

Show:

```
$('body').trigger('processStart');
```

Hide:

```
$('body').trigger('processStop');
```

Refer: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_loader.html

Comment: Thanks, i need to know how to apply in my script, can u pls help with my code?

Comment: Have you tried to add $('body').trigger('processStart'); before this._ajax(.. and $('body').trigger('processStop'); after this._updateItemQtyAfter); ?

Comment: Is my code right : https://codeshare.io/2BEYpm

Comment: updated code : https://codeshare.io/ayeV39

Comment: https://codeshare.io/GqJV9B

Comment: $('body').trigger('processStart');,, shall i use 'body' as it is?

Comment: or shall i use : $('#cart-item-' + itemId + '-qty')

Comment: First, try with the body, you want to show that loader in the specific section, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122779/discussion-between-gem-and-saphal-jha).

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122779/discussion-between-gem-and-saphal-jha